# Insert a new row to GridBagLayout by code from another component

Tags: java, swing

I have a JFrame with some controls positionned with GridBagLayout like this:

```
setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
final GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints;
...
this.add(control, c);
...
```

And I want to insert a row with textfield by code from a button. Is possible to do this ??
I don't have a reference to GridBagConstraints, from now I do it like this:

```
final GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints;
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 0;
...
myframereference.add(mytextfield, c);
...
```

It work and I have a new row at top with my textfield, but when I specify my correct position (gridx = 0 and gridy = 2), all layout breaks.

Thank you.

***EDIT:***

For more informations, a runnable example, I want to insert a new row between label 1 and label 3 from another frame.

```
package test;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LayoutExample extends JFrame {

    public LayoutExample()
    {
        super("Layout Example");
    }

    private void createAndDisplayGUI()
    {       
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        final GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.insets = new Insets(2, 3, 2, 2);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;

        final JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        // Row 1
        final JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Label 1");
        label1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        contentPane.add(label1, c);

        final JTextField textfield1 = new JTextField(8);
        c.gridx++;
        contentPane.add(textfield1, c);

        //------

        final JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Label 2");
        label2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        c.gridx++;
        contentPane.add(label2, c);

        final JTextField textfield2 = new JTextField(8);
        c.gridx++;
        contentPane.add(textfield2, c);

        // Row 2
        final JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Label 3");
        label3.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy++;
        contentPane.add(label3, c);

        final JTextField textfield3 = new JTextField(8);
        c.gridx++;
        contentPane.add(textfield3, c);

        //------

        final JLabel label4 = new JLabel("Label 4");
        label4.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        c.gridx++;
        contentPane.add(label4, c);

        final JTextField textfield4 = new JTextField(8);
        c.gridx++;
        contentPane.add(textfield4, c);

        setContentPane(contentPane);
        pack();
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new LayoutExample().createAndDisplayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I don't have a reference to GridBagConstraints"* - You don't need one; *"all layout breaks"* - An out of context code snippet isn't going to help us help you solve your problem. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Thank you for your reply @MadProgrammer, I just edited my post with a runnable example, i want to insert from another frame a row between label1 and label3.